# django.db.utils.DatabaseError: file is not a database

Tags: django

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 411, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is not a database

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 121, in inn
er_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 459, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 216, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migratio
ns
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    tables = self.connection.introspection.table_names(cursor)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\introspection.py", line 48, in table_na
mes
    return get_names(cursor)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\introspection.py", line 43, in get_name
s
    return sorted(ti.name for ti in self.get_table_list(cursor)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\introspection.py", line 74, in get_t
able_list
    cursor.execute("""
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrapper
s
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\myweb\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 411, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: file is not a database
```

First, the error is "DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed".

The db.sqlite3 file was deleted and re-created and then copied and pasted. Then that kind of error occurs.

What do i do?

Comment: You should elaborate on what you have done to solve the problem. You have not clearly shared what caused this problem and if there is any relevant code associated with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

it can be many problems.

1. check name of the database on disk and in the code. You are using windows so check register of the filename.
2. Maybe it was corrupted somehow, try to create it from scratch. move current db to some folder and run it again.
3. it could be created with different versions of sqllite, check this [sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is not a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58585724/sqlite3-databaseerror-file-is-not-a-database)